# Lenovo Laptop Monitor

Tags: laptop

I have a Lenovo E550 laptop and have a problem when using an external monitor - The problem is the monitor turns blank intermittently for 1-2 seconds and turns on again at random interval. I was using an old LG Monitor and have swapped this out with other identical monitors - same problem. I have 4 other identical computers and they all experience the same problem with varying levels of failure.

I purchased a brand new Samsung LCD Monitor but this delivers the same issue - I am connectine with a standard VGA cable.

What could be the reason for this and how can it be rectified.

Comment: Is the connector loose? You may be affected by the vga Issue an update is [Here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-e550/documents/HT104459?tabName=Solutions)

Comment: Have you tried switching the cable?